# onesignal error: appContext set, but please call setAppId(appId) with a valid appId to complete

Tags: flutter, onesignal

I am facing this error when setup onesignal on flutter.

> appContext set, but please call setAppId(appId) with a valid appId to
> complete OneSignal init

it was showing sometimes. my code was perfect. it's work fine. i also send notification. but it was showing error sometime. why can anyone tell me
here is my code

> await OneSignal.shared.setAppId("c7xxxxx my onesignal id");
> final status = await OneSignal.shared.getDeviceState();
> final String? onesignalUserid = status?.userId;
> print('Onesignal player id: $onesignalUserid');
> onesignlauserid(onesignalUserid);